# Iteration of nested dictionary to find similar values and then add to a list of dictionary with a same key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, networkx

CSV file is taken into networkx graph and iterated to the below format.
Here is the code which I am using to iterate through the dictionary.

```
diction = {
  "1234":{
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"40"
   },
  "2122":{
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"60"
   }
}
new_dict = {}
key_list = []
for key,values in diction.items():
    if key not in key_list:

        name = values['name']
        rollNo = values['rollNo']
        for k,v in diction.items():
            if k not in key_list:
                key_list.append(key)
                key_list.append(k)
                if name == v['name'] and rollNo == v['rollNo']:
                    if (k,key) not in key_list:
                        new_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(v)
                    elif key in key_list:
                        new_dict[key].append(v)
                    elif k in key_list:
                        new_dict[k].append(v)
                else:
                    new_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(v)

print(new_dict)
```

Input:

```
{
  "1234":{ 
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"40"
   },
  "2122":{
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"60"
   }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "1234":[{ 
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"40"
       },
       {
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"60"
      }]
}
```

I have such 5M keys to be checked.
I am currently using for within for which is taking hell lot of time, as the time complexity is n^n.
Want an optimized solution.

Comment: what's the code that you're trying with?

Comment: @VishalSingh updated the question with my code.

Comment: As I understand it, you "merge" the two dictionaries in a list associated to key `"1234"` because they have the same values for keys `"name"` and `"rollNo"`. Is is so?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the algorithmic structure of your code I see one major problem with your code.  In the two lines `key_list.append(key)` and `key_list.append(k)`, `key_list` is assumed to hold `string` values.  But later in `if (k,key) not in key_list` you assume `key_list` to hold `tuple` values (couple of `string`).  So it seems to me that this test will always be evaluated to `True`.

If I understood your problem correctly then this might fix your problem (at least does it produce the desired output for your example):

```py
diction = {
  "1234":{
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"40"
   },
  "2122":{
          "name":"XYZ",
          "rollNo":"2",
          "marks":"60"
   }
}

new_dict = {}
attrib = {}  #  a dictionary mapping (name, rollNo) to diction keys
for key, values in diction.items():
    name = values['name']
    rno = values['rollNo']
    if (name, rno) not in attrib:  #  couple (name, rollNo) unseen so far
        new_dict[key] = [values]
        attrib[(name, rno)] = key  #  record the association(name, rollNo) <-> key
    else:  #  couple (name, rollNo) already seen
        new_dict[attrib[(name, rno)]].append(values)
print(new_dict)
```